# Full text search using linq

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, full-text-search, observablecollection, linq-to-objects

I have a list of names in a observable collection returned from wcf service and database is oracle, I want to make full text search on the list using LINQ.

service is consumed in silverlight application.

Any suggestions pls.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
var found = thelist.Where(str => str.Contains(strToSearchFor));
```

or maybe this -

```
var found = thelist.Where(str => str.ToLower().Contains(strToSearchFor.ToLower()));
```

if it is not list of strings it would like like this:

```
var found = thelist.Where(obj => obj.strProperty.Contains(strToSearchFor));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this solution to be case insensitive the solution of Hogan can be done without creatring a new string (by using the ToLower() method).

First, create an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this string source, string stringToMatch, StringComparison comparisonType)
    {
        return source.IndexOf(stringToMatch, comparisonType) >= 0;
    }
}
```

Then you can make the Hogan solution case insensitive like this:

```
var found = thelist.Where(str => str.Contains(strToSearchFor, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```